# ajax with php, submit if the form is already validated, , bootrap3

Tags: jquery

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('#signup').bootstrapValidator({
    message: 'This value is not valid',
    fields: {
        fname: {
            message: 'The first name name is not valid',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The first name is required \n and can\'t be empty'
                },
                stringLength: {
                    min:4,
                    max: 30,
                    message: 'The first name must be more than 4 and less than 30 characters long'
                },
                regexp: {
                    regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                    message: 'The first name can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                }
            }
        },
   });
 });
```

can someone tell were should i put the ajax to submit my form in php if the is already validated .

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
  $('#signup').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        fields: {
            fname: {
                message: 'The first name name is not valid',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The first name is required \n and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 4,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The first name must be more than 4 and less than 30 characters long'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                        message: 'The first name can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    })
    .on('success.form.bv', function (e) {
       //prevent submit form 
        e.preventDefault();   
        //put your ajax call here

        /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
        $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "post",
        data: val,
        datatype: 'json',
       success: function(data){

       },
      error:function(){

       }   
     }); 

    });
```

[Refrence](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/blob/master/demo/submitHandler.html)

Comment: what do you mean for sucess.form.bv ?

Comment: @MichaelDelgadoBeray it is success method of bootstarp validation plugin. it will fire if form is valid

Comment: it will load in a single page but it will not save the date here my ajax code :

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "reguser.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: true,
            success: function(html){
            $("#showreg").after(html);
            $("#error").hide();
            }  
    });

Comment: i mean data. when i call the php function

Comment: @mics i mention in answer  `//put your ajax call here ` here you can put your ajax call

Answer (score 0):

With a code like this:

```
$('#signup').bootstrapValidator({
    ...
})
.on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
    //Perform form submition (the way you preffer, for example:)
    $.post($('#signup').attr('action'), $('#signup').serialize(), function(response){
        //Form submition response
    });
})
.on('error.form.bv', function(e) {
    //Process error
});;
```

Comment: is it ok if i create new script for ajax ?